# AWS cli command line can not see my key pairs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the aws cli command line tool and graphic interface both configured to the same region.

but I can not access my keypair shown in the graphic interface through command line tool

the command

```
aws ec2 describe-key-pairs
```

returns nothing, even there are key pairs existing in that region.

Reversely, it is the same, when I create a key through

```
aws ec2 create-key test
```

I can not see it from graphic interface.

That was't the case before

Comment: There are 2 possible reasons: (a) different configured region, or (b) different configured credentials. Most likely, it's (a). Try using the `--region` CLI option to explicitly set the region to match the AWS Mangement Console. Also do `aws configure` to see your current configuration.

Comment: @MattHouser  thanks a lot for your suggestion. It was different configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like Matt Houser suggested, it has two reasons
1) different configured credentials
2) different regions